# Idea svn check out, has been keep in the loading, how to solve

Tags: java, svn, intellij-idea

Svn client connection when using the key file and password, no error, that is, after clicking the url no project can choose to stay in the loading.

Comment: Non-answer given as comment: if you happen to work on Windows 10; or on Mac, or Linux: consider switching to git-svn. That is a client that allows you to have a **local** repository that looks like git; but that talks to a remote **svn** server. I found that any client tool with "svn" in its name kept making problems; no matter what. With git-svn, I got rid of all that tooling. And stuff just works.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you use svn+ssh connection URL? The issue seems like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139313

Does checkout work use command line svn client?

If you don't use the command line, try enabling it in Settings - Version control - Subversion. Also, try enabling Interactive mode

Comment: Enabling Interactive mode how to operate？

Comment: I just found it

Comment: Still can not solve, open the Interactive mode is still loading after the time, what other ways?

Answer (score 0):

clear up files in folder C:\Users\your account.IntelliJIdea2018.3\system\vcs,vcsCathe,vcs-users.Then restart your IntelliJIdea.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This answer wold be enhanced by explaining why you would use this solution.